# Changing an image based on the clicked link

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the image based when someone clicks on a link. I have coded this so far:

```
<script>
            function changeImage(e) {
            var elem, evt = e ? e:event;
            alert("Event is"+evt.target);//for testing
            var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
            var feat1 = document.getElementById('feat1');
            var feat2 = document.getElementById('feat2');
            var feat3 = document.getElementById('feat3');
            var feat4 = document.getElementById('feat4');
            if (evt.target.match(feat1.href)) {
                    image.src = "";
                } else {
                    image.src = "";
                }
            }
</script>
```

And HTML:

```
<li><a name="a" href="#1" onclick="changeImage()" id="feat1">a</a></li>
<li><a name="story" href="#2" onclick="changeImage()" id="feat2">b</a></li>
 <li><a name="rep" href="#3" onclick="changeImage()" id="feat3">c</a></li>
 <li><a name="reg" href="#3" onclick="changeImage()" id="feat4">d</a></li>
```

The image does not change. I am using the alert for testing. I am a bit new to javascript so how do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the reference of the current clicked link into `onclick` handler:
html part:

```
<li><a name="a" href="#1" onclick="changeImage(this)" id="feat1">a</a></li>
<li><a name="story" href="#2" onclick="changeImage(this)" id="feat2">b</a></li>
<li><a name="rep" href="#3" onclick="changeImage(this)" id="feat3">c</a></li>
<li><a name="reg" href="#3" onclick="changeImage(this)" id="feat4">d</a></li>
```

Optimize your js part as shown below:

```
<script>
            function changeImage(e) {
            var elem = e.currentTarget,
                id = elem.id,
                href = elem.href;

                if (<your_condition>) {   // exemplary code
                    image.src = "";
                } else {
                    image.src = "";
                }
            }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you do know that in your example, the last two hyperlinks have the same name and href values, right?

Next, onclick as an inline event handler was never standard and is considered bad form. Instead use the DOM standard, addEventListener() as follows:

```
<body>

   <li><a name="a" href="#1" id="feat1">a</a></li>
   <li><a name="story" href="#2" id="feat2">b</a></li>
   <li><a name="rep" href="#3" id="feat3">c</a></li>
   <li><a name="reg" href="#4" id="feat4">d</a></li>

   <img id="myImage" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/NASA_logo.svg/2000px-NASA_logo.svg.png" height="200">

<script>

   (function(){

        var theAnchors = document.querySelectorAll("a[id^='feat']");
        for(var i = 0; i < theAnchors.length; ++i) {
            theAnchors[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
                changeImage(this);
            });
        }

        function changeImage(targetAnchor) {
            var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
            var href = targetAnchor.href;

            if (href.indexOf("#3") > -1) {   
                image.src = "http://www.nasa.gov/centers/jpl/images/content/650602main_pia15415-43.jpg";
            } else {
            alert("else");
                image.src = "http://www.nasa.gov/centers/goddard/images/content/280046main_CassAcomposite_HI.jpg";
            }
        }

    ());  // IIFE

 </script>
</body>
```

In the following JSFiddle, clicking a, b or d will result in the first image going away and a replacement coming up, but when you click c, a different image comes up. Be patient, by the way, these are hi-res images and take a few seconds to load.

Check out a working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/adspxoc5/5/

Comment: Thank you sir. Actually I edited it slightly before pasting it here and I forgot to remove the href value while copy pasting.